# How can I make eclipse to give me a code that I made as a sample code?

Tags: eclipse

When I made a source file in eclipse,
Eclipse gave me a sample code in it.

If i make a HTML file in Eclipse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample code like this came with code file.
I want to change this sample code.

How can I make eclipse to give me a code that I made as a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor > Templates.

Choose the appropriate 'New HTML File (xxxx)' template and click 'Edit...' to change it.

Comment: Thank you. I already give up before check your answer, now I got it. Thank you again.